# Java lambda expression is treated as a function, so compiler does not create .class file. this is Wrong, right?

Tags: lambda, java-8, expression

```
interface Sayable{  
    public String say();  
}  
public class LambdaExpressionExample3{  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Sayable s=()->{  
        return "I have nothing to say.";  
    };  
    System.out.println(s.say());  
}  
}
```

I ran this example on my machine , but it did Create the Sayable.class file.

Comment: Look at your code, do you see a class? :) If you want to learn more, read about [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html?is-external=true)

Comment: That's what i am saying it created Sayable.class file.

Comment: `Sayable.class` file is created due to the declaration of the interface, it has nothing to do with the lambda

Comment: Okay. So my Question was that Only , That sentence i wrote it was on  [JavaTPOINT] https://www.javatpoint.com/java-lambda-expressions. Third Para

Answer (score 1):

The `Sayable.class` is created because you defined it in your code. Try removeing the lambda and you'll see that it still be created.

That's just how java works. Classes, interfaces and enums which are defined in the same .java file (as package private or inner doesn't matter) get their own .class file after compilation

Comment: Ya so the statement i post in my question is wrong right ? that is what i am asking . Because it is on [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-lambda-expressions), as i mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: @jack_07 i don't understand what you mea , in the link you provided there is nothing thats says anything about .class files

Comment: Third Para . Java lambda expression is treated as a function, so compiler does not create .class file.

Comment: yes that is true. Your interface `Sayable` does create a .class file, and the implementation doesn't. So you have a Sayable.class but not a Lambda$Sayable.class or something similar